# how to access json file using jquery AJAX method

Tags: jquery

I have tried ,but I got error.

```
(Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed))
```

json file is **dataJSON.js**

```
items: [
    {
        empid:2192,
        name:"hari",
        designation: "software engineer"
    },
    {
        empid: 2392,
        name: "bala",
        designation: "software engineer"
    }
],
```

**AJAX call :**

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "dataJSON.js",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    data: {},
    success: function (response) {
        alert('test');
    }       
});
```

please tell some the solution, I think url is a problem. How to use js file into the ajax url ?

Comment: i think you should change the type to get not post

Comment: First, i think you are just trying to 'read' data, why not use "GET"? As for the url, where (at which url) is the data loaded from the server? The way you are specifying it looks alright.

Comment: You better use a `GET` than a `POST` to get things. That said this doesn't explain this specific error message which generally occurs when trying to use a more uncommon method like `DELETE`. Is your JS file located in the same location aas your HTML file ?

Comment: `datatype` should be `dataType` see [$.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

The url is ok, if there is issue with the url, it would send 404 error. Try using get request.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "dataJSON.js",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {},
    success: function (response) {
        alert('test');
    }       
});
```